# Changing numpy array with array of indices

Tags: numpy

I have an array in numpy:
`A=np.zeros((5,10))`
and I want to change one value in each row with ones according to another array `N=np.array([7, 2, 9, 4, 5])`

like:  `A[:,N]=1;`

```
0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Which row of each column?

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to set *a single element per row*, you need to fancy-index the first axis using `arange(5)`. this can be thought of as setting indices `(I0[0], N[0])=(0,7)`, `(I0[1],N[1])=(1,2)`, ...

```
I0 = np.arange(A.shape[0])
A[I0, N] = 1
A
=> 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
A.nonzero()
=> (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([7, 2, 9, 4, 5]))
```